# iOS: Warnings when handling didSelectViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

The following code:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]) {
        MySearchViewController *controller = viewController;
        [[controller tableView] reloadData];
    }
}
```

Yields the following warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'MySearchViewController *__strong' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *__strong'
```

What would be the proper way to cast `viewController` into the proper class `MySearchViewController` to call its method?

Comment: Did you simply try `MySearchViewController *controller = (MySearchViewController *)viewController;`?

Comment: Hey, that's great. Is that... proper casting in Objective C?

Comment: It just tells the compiler that you know it's of that type, so it doesn't show the warning. It doesn't do anything to the object. So if viewController turns out to be an other type of class, it will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change to this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] && [viewController isKindOfClass:[MySearchViewController class]]) {
        MySearchViewController *controller = (MySearchViewController *)viewController;
        [[controller tableView] reloadData];
    }
}
```